# Extract filenames and ext. from cell array of strings

Tags: octave

I want to remove the directory part from a cell array of strings with filenames. Of course one way would be to loop over the cell arrray and use `fileparts` but I have over 1e5 files and speed really matters.

My current approach is:

```
fns = {"/usr/local/foo.lib", "~/baz.m", "home/rms/eula.txt", "bar.m"}

filenames = cellfun (@(fn, s) fn(s+1:end), fns,
                     num2cell (rindex (fns, filesep())),
                     "UniformOutput", false)
```

which gives the desired output:

```
fns = 
{
  [1,1] = /usr/local/foo.lib
  [1,2] = ~/baz.m
  [1,3] = home/rms/eula.txt
  [1,4] = bar.m
}
filenames = 
{
  [1,1] = foo.lib
  [1,2] = baz.m
  [1,3] = eula.txt
  [1,4] = bar.m
}
```

and takes approx 2e-5s per file. Is there a better (faster, more readable) way to do this?

**EDIT** I've added Sardars solution and my previous attempt with regex and some benchmark results:

```
fns = {"/usr/local/foo.lib", "~/baz.m", "home/rms/eula.txt", "bar.m"};
fns = repmat (fns, 1, 1e4);

tic
f1 = cellfun (@(fn, s) fn(s+1:end), fns,
              num2cell (rindex (fns, "/")),
              "UniformOutput", false);
toc

tic
[~, ~, ~, M] = regexp (fns, "[^\/]+$", "lineanchors");
f2 = cell2mat (M);
toc

tic
## Asnwer from Sardar Usama
f3 = regexprep(fns, '.*/', ''); 
toc

assert (f1, f2)
assert (f1, f3)
```

which gives

```
Elapsed time is 0.729995 seconds.  (Original code with cellfun)
Elapsed time is 0.67545 seconds.   (using regexp)
Elapsed time is 0.230487 seconds.  (using regexprep)
```

Comment: `regexprep(fns, '[^]*/', '')` works in MATLAB, but gives an error in Octave. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @SardarUsama `[^]` does not make any sense. The `[]` make a bracketed character class, so having a single character there, `^`, is pointless. Also, when you use `^` to start a bracketed character class, the class will match all characters not in the list. So you are starting a "negative" character class but your list of characters is empty.

Comment: @carandraug Explain how it makes sense to MATLAB

Comment: @SardarUsama that's just how this type of regular regular expressions work. That Matlab does not error on `[^]` is weird. Matlab also itself states in `regexprep` that `[^c1c2c3]` is a metacharacter but does not explain what happens when `c1c2c3` is empty. Octave errors. So does perl and python. So will do anything using libpcre.

Comment: I guess matlab must interpret "[^]" as the "match everything" character. Which is weird, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`regexprep`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFregexprep) to search the strings till the last `/` and replace the occurrences with an empty string.

```
filenames = regexprep(fns, '.*/', '');
```

Comment: Check speed comparison of this solution with yours here: http://rextester.com/NWIGO96217

Comment: Nice solution. I wonder why I haven't thought on this.
I've added some benchmarks with your solution to the question with 40000 strings (you benchmark isn't really significant with only 4 strings)

Comment: @Andy By 4, do  you mean 100,000? :D btw I didn't change the script in last 19hrs